# Angular 5 EventEmmiter return not only values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a component to add list of product genres (e.g. 'Dramma', 'Comedy', etc.). The code of component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { GENRES } from '../mock-genres';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'genre',
  template: `
    <label for="genres">Жанр(ы)</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="genres" (change)="addGenre(genre)" #genre>
      <option *ngFor="let genre of genresList">{{ genre }}</option>
    </select>
    <ul id="genres-list" class="list-group">
      <li
        class="list-group-item genre"
        *ngFor="let genre of genres"
        (click)="removeGenre(genreItem.innerText)"
        #genreItem>
        {{ genre }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./genre.component.scss']
})
export class GenreComponent implements OnInit {

  genres: String[] = [];
  @Input('type') type: String;
  @Output('change') change = new EventEmitter<String[]>();
  public genresList: String[];

  ngOnInit() {
    switch (this.type) {
      case 'films':
        this.genresList = GENRES.filmGenres;
        break;
      case 'books':
        this.genresList = GENRES.bookGenres;
        break;
      case 'music':
        this.genresList = GENRES.musicGenres;
        break;
    }
  }

  addGenre(genre: HTMLInputElement) {
    if (genre.value !== '') {
      this.genres.push(genre.value);
      this.change.emit(this.genres);
    }
  }

  removeGenre(genre) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.genres.length; i++) {
      if (this.genres[i] === genre) {
        this.genres.splice(i, 1);
        this.change.emit(this.genres);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This is how I call it in outer component:

```
<genre (change)="updateGenres($event)" [type]="'books'"></genre>
```

But when I'm trying to add new genre, `$event` object return not only updated genres, but also an `Event` object.

[$event value after adding genre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAwfj.png)

The things getting more weird when I delete a genre. Because in this case it doesn't return any `Event` object.

[$event value after deleting genre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzXed.png)

Comment: Can you show your updateGenres code?

Comment: There are to many things wrong with this source code to narrow it down to one possible cause. I recommend that you read more tutorials on how to interact with forms using Angular, and try to forget your past experience writing JavaScript that directly manipulates the DOM. I'm not criticizing this, but I can see from the code that you're still solving problems by accessing the DOM directly. Had you followed common Angular practices this question wouldn't have been asked.http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

Comment: I can't replicate what you have got. This is version 6.x anyway. See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqka9q

Answer (score 0):

I think the different function definitions may be the cause of this dicrepancy. Can you make them both same once and check the console agaon.

```
removeGenre(genre) {

addGenre(genre: HTMLInputElement) {
```

Or 
Use the following link to know how eventemitter works in angular.
https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2